# Image resizing with dynamic frame

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax

I'm completely stuck and I need help. I've been trying to create a picture framing utility (for photos etc). where the user can specify the size of their photo, then choose a coloured cardboard mount and a frame type to go around it.
The site my client chose for me to create something similar to is this: http://www.ezeframe.co.uk/picture-frames

You can see that the user can specify their picture size, frame and mount, and see it taking shape on screen. Where I've come unstuck is the scaling. You can see in the above example that if someone changes their mount size or frame type, they change so that they remain in proportion to the picture size.
I've been trying to make my system do the same and I'm failing!

What I've done so far (without scaling) can be seen on the clients live site here: www.vivarti.co.uk/bespoke-frames

I've done it mostly using CSS, Jquery and AJAX.

Is there a better way to do this kind of thing than using Jquery, or can anyone help me work out the maths to make my version scale? A tall order I know but I'm just hoping someone can help me!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

or use CSS

```
<body style="max-width: 90%; max-height: 90%">
    <div id="div_container" style="background: #ff3300;max-width: 90%; max-height: 90%">
        <img id="imgid" src="picture.jpg" style="max-width: 90%; max-height: 90%">
    </div
</body>
```

you can also use javascript to set the max/min-Width

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I don't think that work in this case. The frames are all specific widths, and the user can specify a specific mount width as well.

Comment: Can anyone help?? Please?

Comment: in my case, in order to update the size of the image, i only need to modify the size of the div with id = 'div_container' using javascript:

Comment: e.g. document.getElementById('div_container').style.height = heigth + "px";

Comment: Hi Ulrich, Thanks for your comment. Is there anywhere I can see your script in action, so I can see if it does something similar to what I need?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function setHeight(value) {
                getTag('div_container').style.height = value + 'px';
            }

            function setWidth(value) {
                getTag('div_container').style.width = value + 'px';
            }

            function getTag(id) {
                return document.getElementById(id);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <input type="text" value="200" onChange="setHeight(this.value);"
                 placeholder="height">
            <input type="text" value="200" onChange="setWidth(this.value);"           
                 placeholder="width">
        </div>
        <div id="div_container" style="background: #ff3300;width:200px;   
             height:200px;max-width: 90%; max-height: 90%">
            <img id="imgid" src="http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/stackoverflow-sticker-proof.png" 
                style="min-width: 5%; min-height: 5%; max-width: 90%; max-height: 90%; margin: 5%;">
        </div>
  </body>
```